# MVC show session value in HTML

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net-mvc

Im am doing an `MVC` Application, and I have to Redirect to a plane `HTML page`. I need to show the user name.

I think the only way to pass value from `Controller` to HTML Page is via `Session Value`.

Here is my code

```html
 public ActionResult Index()
        {
            Session["Username"] = "My Name";
            return new FilePathResult("pagehtml", "text/html");
            }
```

In My HTML page I set this

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<script type='text/javascript'>
    var userID = '<%=Session["Username"]%>';
    alert(userID);
</script>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>My Page</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

the problem is that `alert(userID);`

Shows `<%=Session["Username"]%>` instead of the value.

How can i get `Session` value? or if there another way to pass value from `Controller` to an standar HTML..

thanks

Comment: are you using aspx view engine?

Comment: I think you need razor syntax if you are using mvc try `var userID = '@Session["Username"]';`

Comment: Pete, is the same, it took it as string text... Thanks